# How to get concatenated list of unique items in array in JS/TS

Tags: angular, firebase, lodash

I have object below:

```
let menu = [
  {name: 'Hambuger_1', categories: ['cheese', 'mushroom']  },
  {name: 'Hamburger_2', categories: ['cheese', 'bacon', 'tomato']}
]
```

And I need an array `categories = [cheese, mushroom, bacon, tomato]`

I'm using _.uniqBy but it's not considering the arrays as unique, how can I get an array of the unique values for all categories?

I'm using Angular 12 and Firestore, so I have the code like below, but of course as I have arrays, all are diferent:

```
this.categories$ = this.fbs.getProducts().pipe(map(data => _.uniqBy(data,'category')))
```

Comment: On top you have array of objects no object. `[]` = array `{}` = object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the array of `categories` using `Array.flatMap()`, and pass the array through a `Set` to make in unique:

```js
const menu = [{name: 'Hambuger_1', categories: ['cheese', 'mushroom'] }, {name: 'Hamburger_2', categories: ['cheese', 'bacon', 'tomato']}]

const result = [...new Set(menu.flatMap(o => o.categories))]

console.log(result)
```

With lodash, use `_.flatMap()` to get the items, then use `_.uniq()` to remove duplicates:

```js
const menu = [{name: 'Hambuger_1', categories: ['cheese', 'mushroom'] }, {name: 'Hamburger_2', categories: ['cheese', 'bacon', 'tomato']}]

const result = _.uniq(_.flatMap(menu, 'categories'))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```